# Any Google Places API for checking if a location falls on a specific route?

Tags: google-places-api

I am working on a car pooling application and have the following requirement:

Locations A, B, C and D located in that order in a route. 
**[A -> B -> C -> D]**
That is, if one wants to go from A to D, he has to go through B and C.

Now the requirement is:

1. A ride is available from A to D.
2. Another user is looking for a ride from A to C.
3. For this user, the ride from A to D should be suggested.

Are there any relevant Google APIs for meeting this requirement?

Regards,
Shiva

Answer (score 0):

Use the Waypoints feature of the Google Maps Directions API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints.

You may find the "Optimize your waypoints" section particularly helpful.